# Does the number of elements in Vector space and the dimension of Vector space same?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, dimension-theory-algebra

The number of elements in any basis of a vector space is called the dimension of Vector space.

In the Vector space F^n(F) and Null Space; the dimension of Vector Space and the number of Vectors in the Vector Space are distinct.

Does the number of elements in the Vector Space and the Dimension of Vector Space always distinct???

If not,then in which case number of elements in Vector Space and the Dimension of Vector Space both are equal??

Comment: This is not clear.  What field are you working over?  are you restricting to finite fields?  Are you restricting to finite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: I am asking about both finite dimensional vector space and infinite dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 1):

We focus on finite-dimensional cases, where we can prove without much effort the dimension and the number of elements never agree.

First suppose we work over an infinite field $\mathbb{F}$ (e.g.$\mathbb{Q}$,$\mathbb{R}$,$\mathbb{C}$). In this case, any finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ has infinitely many elements. (As an example, we may consider $\mathbb{R}$ itself as a $1$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, which has infinitely many elements. )

Then suppose $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field of $q$ elements. By the definition of a field, we have $q>1$. It's clear that an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ has $q^n$ elements. So again, we conclude $q^n > n$.

If we do not restrict ourselves to finite-dimensional vector spaces, things can be subtler.

Comment: The last statement is not correct. The dimension of the reals as a vector space over the rationals is equal to the cardinality of the reals.

Comment: Thank you for your correction.

Comment: What would be in case of infinite dimensional vector space??

Comment: @ManasUpadhyay If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal and $\kappa \geqslant \operatorname{card} F$, then an $F$-vector space of dimension $\kappa$ has $\kappa$ elements. If $\lambda < \operatorname{card} F$, then a $\lambda$-dimensional vector space over $F$ has more than $\lambda$ elements ($1$ for $\lambda = 0$, and at least $\operatorname{card} F > \lambda$ for $\lambda \geqslant 1$).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your remark. Although I know this is a pure set-theoretic issue, I wonder if there is any quick source to refer to.

Comment: Please give more precise example.

Comment: I don't know about a quick source, but it's a quick consequence of the fact that a vector space is the union of the subspaces spanned by the finite subsets of a basis. The cardinality of a finite-dimensional space is $\leqslant \max \:\{\aleph_0, \operatorname{card} F\}$, so for infinite $\kappa$ and $\dim V = \kappa$ we have $$\kappa \leqslant \operatorname{card} V \leqslant \kappa\cdot \max \:\{\aleph_0, \operatorname{card} F\} = \max\:\{\kappa, \operatorname{card} F\}$$ since a) the basis is a subset of $V$ ("is" isn't quite correct if you define a basis as an indexed family),

Comment: b) $\kappa \geqslant \aleph_0$, and c) a set of cardinality $\kappa$ has exactly $\kappa$ finite subsets (and sum and product of infinite cardinals is just the maximum). Of course, as always, everything goes out the window if you reject choice.